# Unique Rows to three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables, and all three tables have the same Request ID field.

- Sched_G includes all data
- where every row in Sched_P and Sched_I exists in Sched_G.
- but not every row of Sched_G exists in P or I.

I'm looking for all rows where it exists in Sched_G and Sched_I, but does not exist in Sched_P.

The Request ID are the same and the primary key to all three tables. Which would be the simplest way? I tried using Join statements but got stuck and also wheres g.primary_key = r.primary_key, but this causes no data to appear. Any help?

Comment: You are looking for all the rows where "it" exists...  What is "**it**"? **Rows** from which table? (You said the three tables have a column in common, but otherwise I assume they are different - so, rows from WHICH table?) Or are you only looking for `Request_Id` which exists in `Sched_I` but not in `Sched_P`? You said "in `Sched_G` and `Sched_I` but not in..." - Why do you need to check that they are in `Sched_G`? You said every "row" (I assume only every "Request_Id") in `Sched_I` exists in `Sched_G`, so you don't need to check `Sched_G` **and** `Sched_I`, the second suffices.

Comment: In any case, you don't need either joins or `MINUS` for this; you need an "anti-join" (which does less work than a join). Something as simple as `select request_id from schedule_I where request_id not in (select request_id from schedule_P)`.

Answer (score 1):

This give you all G in I

```
SELECT G.*
FROM G
JOIN I
  ON G.Request_id = I.Request_id
```

Now you want to know which of those arent in P

```
SELECT G.*
FROM G
JOIN I
  ON G.Request_id = I.Request_id
LEFT JOIN P 
  ON G.Request_id = P.Request_id
WHERE P.Request_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use MINUS if you are using Oracle:

```
select * 
from Sched_G t1 join Sched_I t2 on t1.RequestID= t2.RequestID
minus
select RequestID from Sched_P
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for all rows where it exists in Sched_G and Sched_I

Do a `INNER JOIN` saying

```
select sg.* from sched_g sg inner join sched_i si
on sg.id = si.id;
```

Then do a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select xxx.*
from (
    select sg.* from sched_g sg inner join sched_i si
    on sg.id = si.id ) xxx
left join sched_p sp on xxx.id = sp.id
where sp.some_col is null;
```

Comment: I dont think you need a subquery for this?